# Remainder with double exponent?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am asked to find

$$13 ^{13^{13}} \bmod 10$$

I know how this works if it's just $a^p \bmod x$ with a single prime exponent but I'm not sure how to reduce the double power.
Also pretty sure this still involves Fermat's theorem but not sure how to apply it with the $2$ powers.

Comment: Hint: $13^4 = 28561 \equiv 1 \bmod {10}$ and $13^1 =13 \equiv 1 \bmod {4}$

Comment: For those of you who are confused, % often means $\mod$ in coding.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thanks for clarifying I sometimes forget I'm posting in a math forum and not the CS one

Comment: There’s some ambiguity in the computer notation 13 ^ 13 ^ 13. I think it means $13^{(13^{13})}$, not $(13^{13})^{13}$, but one never knows.

Comment: I think it is a convention that $\large a^{b^c}$ means $\large a^{(b^c)}$

Comment: @Lubin:  in math, $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{\left(b^c\right)}$ because $\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{bc}$ and is not so useful.  I don't know about computer languages.

Comment: @RossMillikan, right you are. My ever-failing memory tells me that I once heard a coder say that in this case you read from right to left, giving the same result. But it’s extremely disquieting to see a manifestly nonassociative operation written on one line without parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to know how to read it.  $13^{13^{13}}=13^{ \left( 13^{13} \right)}$.  Now you only have one exponent, which is $13^{13}=302875106592253$ and you can use Fermat's little theorem.  Find $k$ such that $13^k \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$, then take $13^{13} \pmod k$

Comment: Considering what the value of $k$ turns out to be, you don’t even need to know $13^{13}$ .

Answer (score 0):

$13^{8}\equiv 1 \pmod {10}$

$13^{13}\equiv 5\pmod 8$

$13^{13} = 5 + 8k$

$13^{13^{13}}\equiv 13^{5+8k}\equiv 13^5 \pmod {10}$

Comment: Actually $13^4 \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$ which would make calculations even easier.

Comment: And $13^m\equiv1\pmod4$ no matter what the value of $m$.