# Double exponent Euler- FLT

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am asked to determine 
$13^{13^{13}} \bmod 10$ and $13^{13^{13}} \bmod 15$

I know I have to use the Fermat's Little Theorem and Euler and find a $k$ s.t. $13^k\equiv 1 \pmod{10}$. By trial and error I found $k=4$. However, I don't quite understand what's happening here. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937716/remainder-with-double-exponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can find that $k$ is a divisor of $4$ by Euler's Formula. Anyway now we want to find the residue of $13^{13}$ modulo $4$. Assume it's $n$ and $13^{13} = 4m + n$. Then we have that:

$$13^{13^{13}} \equiv 13^{4m + n} \equiv (13^4)^m \cdot 13^n \equiv 1^m \equiv 13^n \pmod{10}$$

Therefore we have effectivelly reduced the problem to computing the residue of a much smaller number.

Now you should be able to finish this on you own, as well as solve the second question.

Comment: I got 3 as the answer - is that correct?

Comment: @user1023 Yes, as $13^{13} \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \implies n=1$, which means that $13^{13^{13}} \equiv 13^1 \equiv 3 \pmod {10}$

Comment: So for the 2nd one, we get $13^{13} \equiv 1 (mod 8)$, right?

Comment: @user1023 I'm afraid not. Note that $13^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, then $13^{13} \equiv 13 \equiv 5 \pmod 8$

Comment: For your comment for the 1st part, did you mean to write $13^1 \equiv 3 (mod 4)$ and not mod 10?

Comment: @user1023 Everything is alright. Eventually you will have to backtrack and that's why you should return to the initial modulo.

Comment: Oh I asked that because for the comment on 2nd question its mod 8 and not mod 15. I'm sorry, I'm just really confused

Comment: @user1023 I was just refering to the fact that you've miscalculated something. Eventually you will have to use the information that $13^{13} \equiv 5 \pmod 8$ to get that $13^{13^{13}} \equiv 13^5 \equiv 13 \pmod {15}$

Comment: So the answer for 2nd part is 13, right?